# Why is my included JSP not found?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jspinclude

The `main.jsp` is location in this directory of the web app:

```
/WEB-INF/jsps/foo/section/main.jsp
```

`main.jsp` contains the following line of code to try to include the code contained in `mainInclude.jsp` which is found in a different directory:

```
<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/jsps/foo/includes/mainInclude.jsp" />
```

However, this generates the following error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: 
File '/WEB-INF/jsps/foo/includes/mainInclude.jsp' not found
```

Why is this not found? I checked the location and it appears where it says it is.

Comment: Double check - it should work! Any typos, upper-lower case, etc.?

Answer (score 5):

Change your jsp include tag like this

```
<jsp:include page="../includes/mainInclude.jsp" />
```

That should work. Check the eclipses if they are taking to the foo directory else put one more **../** there.

Answer (score 2):

Everything looks fine. If you get that error then it simply means that you've a typo in the path (case sensitive!), or that the file actually isn't been published/deployed into the server, or that the server actually needs to be restarted.

If you're developing with for example Eclipse/Tomcat and you just added that file while Tomcat is running, then you need to ensure that Tomcat is configured to publish changes while running. To achieve that, doubleclick Tomcat's entry in *Servers* view, head to the *Publishing* section on the right top and make sure that it's set as follows:

[image]

---

It's namely by default set to *Never publish automatically*.

Comment: I think this is the default. Also, I think when "publishing" it restarts the server, while if you 'never publish', resources still get copied, and it's up to tomcat to pick them up. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Depends likely on server plugin used. But indeed, Tomcat is a very poor publisher. Glassfish is way much better.

Answer (score -1):

```
This should work <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/jsps/foo/includes/mainInclude.jsp"/>
```

- If the problem still exists clean the project properly.
- Check whether if the Auto publish is enabled in server settings of eclipse.
- A WAR file of project can be used to deploy in server to check there is any problem in Eclipse.

  [Get the WEB-INF folder path](http://melandri.net/2009/05/28/get-the-web-inf-folder-path/)